# Extract field values from DataType

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm adding a PendingIntent listener to a sensor that read samples of the current activity using the code:

```
Fitness.SensorsApi.add(
            googleApiClient,
            new SensorRequest.Builder()
                    .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SAMPLE)
                    .setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .build(), pendingIntent);
```

On my intentService, i can extract the DataPoint from the intent using [`DataPoint.extract(intent)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/SensorsApi.html#add(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.SensorRequest, android.app.PendingIntent)). From the dataPoint i get the DataType using [getDataType()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataPoint.html#getDataType()), but then i stuck in reading the the values(in this case are *activity* and *confidence* from [*com.google.activity.sample*](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#public_data_types)) from the DataType.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage this by calling [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataPoint.html#getValue(com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Field)) of DataPoint passing the [Field](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/Field) (in this case `Field.FIELD_ACTIVITY` and `Field.FIELD_CONFIDENCE`). Then i need to convert the [Value](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/Value).

`dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_CONFIDENCE).asFloat()`
`dataResult.getValue(Field.FIELD_ACTIVITY).asActivity()`